# How to compare 2 lists with multiple rows per element?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find a way of comparing two lists of "people" with several rows per person against another list where they may or may not contain the same rows.

Each person has a singular ID unique to them. For each person in either list, there can be between 1 and 4 rows. They might not necessarily contain the same number of rows or they might not be in the same order. Other than that, per person, almost every cell in each row is going to be redundant and identical (mainly personal information that doesn't vary). The possible rows ("items") are always the same: Jackets, Hats, Shoes and Accesories. The last two cells in each row are the actual value I need to compare.

English is my second language and I'm having a terrible time trying to put it into words, [so I made an example on Google Sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtyqwoJZ4l6_gTyzv5AjlAzRy-4rz8o9Vv1GF6FB6XA/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm also getting both of these tables with the specific columns and format as in the example I'm linking and I cannot change that or rearrange it. All I can do is add the "Went over?" column.

It sounds to me like I need something like a more sophisticated version of VLOOKUP, where I can look for the unique ID (col. B), then somehow also look for the item (col. E) and return the amount value for that specific item (col. F). Then it's just a matter of IF A=B then "OK!", etc.. But I don't know a function that works like a double VLOOKUP, sort of speak.

Can you good people of SU point me in the right direction of how to come up with a way of producing the "comparison" column in N in a way that doesn't require scripting? Otherwise, how can I compare each element for each person vs. same elements for the same person in the other list?

##### Example Table 1

| NAME | VENDOR ID # | SEX | AGE | ITEMS EXPECTED | AMOUNT EXPECTED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Jackets | 44 |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Hats | 20 |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Shoes | 55 |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Accessories | 18 |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Hats | 56 |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Shoes | 20 |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Accessories | 26 |
| DOE, JOHN | 1235554 | M | 54 | Jackets | 80 |
| DOE, JOHN | 1235554 | M | 54 | Accessories | 20 |

##### Example Table 2

| NAME | VENDOR ID # | SEX | AGE | ITEMS SOLD | AMOUNT SOLD | WENT OVER? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Jackets | 44 | OK! |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Shoes | 65 | +10 |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Hats | 20 | OK! |
| WATTS, TOM | 6505581 | M | 21 | Accessories | 18 | OK! |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Accessories | 26 | OK! |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Shoes | 10 | -10 |
| SMITH, JANE | 702452 | F | 32 | Hats | 56 | OK! |
| DOE, JOHN | 1235554 | M | 54 | Jackets | 95 | +15 |
| DOE, JOHN | 1235554 | M | 54 | Accessories | 22 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's nothing missing. The idea was to check table A vs table B, which are going to be on the same sheet. Also, the tables aren't identical, even though most of the information is redundant. The order of the rows is not the same and neither are the values in some of the rows. Edited my post to show the tables, like you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A solution without tables and `LET`

Now I've used a helper column to get expected amount first (in order to keep final formula more simple):
`=FILTER($F$2:$F$10,($B$2:$B$10=I2)*($E$2:$E$10=L2))`

Than the main formula just compares sold amount vs expected amount:
`=IF(M2=N2,"OK!",M2-N2)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for tagging the post wrong and wasting your time, but I can't add tags and couldn't find "Google Sheets".

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is `FILTER()`, on top of that I've used `LET()` function to make formula simpler, and added tables (insert - table), so I can use structured references.

`=LET(expected, FILTER(Table1[AMOUNT EXPECTED],(Table1[VENDOR ID '#]=[@[VENDOR ID '#]])*(Table1[ITEMS EXPECTED]=[@[ITEMS SOLD]])),IF(expected=[@[AMOUNT SOLD]],"OK!",[@[AMOUNT SOLD]]-expected))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I've been trying to reverse engineer this to see if I can figure it out, but I'm not really familiar with using formulas on tables (not really familiar with tables, either!) and I'm stumped. The reason I can't do it this way is because I'll have to work on Google Sheets (again, not up to me) where I don't have LET() nor tables. I tried referencing cells instead of the table references but I can't seem to figure it out, specfiically the filter condition. It seems like it's multiplying the IDs or something, which obviously can't be right.

Comment: If you're working on Google sheets, please don't tag your question as Excel. That way you can avoid getting unhelpful answers and people spending their time without use.